# What is the purpose of the AT-ACT?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

With cargo shuttle craft being prevalent in the Star Wars universe, what would be the purpose of the AT-ACT? Wouldn't a shuttle be more useful?

Answer (score 31):

Look at what the initials stand for: *All Terrain, Armored* Cargo Transport.

The design of the AT-AT and AT-ACT is meant to be:

- Heavily armored, so it can withstand a beating. Basically, it's a huge personnel-carrying tank.
- All-terrain. The long legs and quadrupedal walking style gives it the ability to maneuver around almost any kind of terrain. This includes places that would be hard for a ground-based speeder or an air-based shuttle to reach. This includes hilly terrain, steppes, swamps, forests, etc, all without having to prepare a landing area in advance.

(Note that, in the "real world", engineers are *constantly* trying to build robots that can walk like 4- or 6- or 8-legged animals rather than roll around on wheels or treads, for the same reason.)

Comment: I thought we were trying to make walking robots for the coolness factor.

Comment: While these details never really manifest in the films, perhaps the ground walkers can A) lift/carry more than a shuttle and B) require far less maintenance/pilot skill, so they are more economical than flying stuff everywhere. But since every child seems to be a pilot/mechanic in the Star Wars universe, perhaps this is irrelevant :)

Comment: "This includes places that would be hard for ... an air-based shuttle to reach." - Couldn't an air-based shuttle "reach" anywhere an AT-ACT could reach? And potentially lower its cargo if not able to land?

Comment: @Terriblefan it's for nightmare fuel, actually ;)

Comment: Also the AT ATs can move INSIDE of huge buildings and also underground what shuttles normally can't

Comment: There are lots of examples of vehicles that seem to hover over all types of terrain in the Star Wars universe.  Your answer doesn't effectively explain how walking would be superior.

Answer (score 5):

Economics are not discussed much but presumably the same reason cargo is still moved by truck and rail even though we have airplanes, it's cheaper overall.

Answer (score 1):

Control of  element domain is in question, as well as risks and economic factor. They deal with different planets, some have conditions where air units will be ineffective. If you don't have air superiority or enemy got control of air space by SAMs and AA turrets, then you do not want to transport your troops by air.

Answer (score -1):

These answers are not entirely correct.

While I think the AT-ACT is impractical and reallly only in the movie to be a bigger and different version of the AT-AT, these vehicles are supposed to be cargo transports. They carry kyber crystals and such. They drivers do not have mylitary licenses, necessarily. So why do they have those badass guns and why are they taller than the AT-AT? To have a bassas ground war scene.

In my opinion, they should have used the AT-ATs and AT-STs from Rebels.

AT-ATs need armour to transport troops into battle. Their hieght makes them terrifying.

AT-ACTs do not need armour or weapons because they are not combat vehicles. Also, their hieght would be inefficient because you'd have to get the cargo (orange box) way up there. Finally, did you notice how small the cargo container is in relation to the vehicle? The AT-ACT should have had a flat bed in the back that a much larger cargo container could rest on.

Worst of all, when you watch the movie, you have no reason to think there is any mining or cargo transporting going on. That is just a factoid you have to read about.

Here are three better ways to move materials of Scarif:
1. Barges 
2. Trucks (the huge ones mines use)
3. Assuming those cargo containers can levitate into position, kill the AT-ACT and just use hover cargo containers.

But, all of those would be lame in battle, as a cargo vehicle should be. That is why I would go with the AT-AT from Rebels (pictured). Or, change the script entirely so that the plans were stollen during a space battle, as per the crawl, not during a ground attack which isn't really a great spy tactic.

[image]

Comment: Most of this seems to be criticism of the movie, and doesn’t address the actual question.

Comment: The advantage of the AT-ACT’s size is a longer stride, and thus greater speed. The compromise is weaker structural stability (ion cannons, anyone?), which is why similar-sized units are not frequently used in combat.